# React Router 4 after logout manage route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to react, I have been working on implementing basic authentication process with Meteor, I am using `React Router V4` for routing, below is the code of my routes to get basic idea:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}  onEnter={onEnterPublicPage}/>
        <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} onEnter={onEnterPublicPage}/>
        <Route exact path='/links' component={Link}/>
          <Route exact path='*' component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
);
```

Here is the basic authentication flow which I am expecting:

> Login Screen > Home Screen(press logout) > Login Screen

This flow is achieved by using below code:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
 const isAuthenticated= !!Meteor.userId();
 console.log('isAuthenticated', isAuthenticated);
   if (isAuthenticated && isUnAuthenticatedPage){
     history.push('/links');
   }
   else if (!isAuthenticated && isAuthenticatedPage){
     history.push('/');
   }
});
```

Through this code after logout when I get landed to Root i.e. Login Screen, by pressing back button of browser I am again redirected to Home Screen which should not happen according to the expected flow. How can I manage this situation?

I was trying to clear the browser history after logout, but I believe that is not the best practice to achieve this flow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `history.replace()` instead of `history.push()`

**Why?**

When you call history.push interface, it will add a new state **on top of history stack** (so you can go previous history state by clicking back button of the browser), while history.replace will replace **current history state with a new one** which you defined.